# DELETE request's preflight fails on Firefox for Quarkus

Tags: reactjs, firefox, quarkus, auth0, http-status-code-400

I'm getting a very strange error which I'm having a very hard time understanding why it's occurring.

### Setup

I have a Quarkus backend which serves the following endpoints:

```
@Path("/rest/manager")
@ApplicationScoped
public class ManagerController {

    ...

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    public Response getManagerList() {
        ...
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/")
    public Response createManager(@Valid ManagerView managerView) {
        ...
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{userId}")
    public Response getManager(@Parameter(required = true) @PathParam("userId") String userId) {
        ...
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{userId}")
    public Response deleteManager(@Parameter(required = true) @PathParam("userId") String userId) {
        ...
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{userId}")
    public Response updateManager(@PathParam("userId") String userId, @Valid ManagerView managerView) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Quarkus `application.properties` looks like this:

```
quarkus.http.cors=true
quarkus.http.cors.origins=http://localhost:3000
quarkus.http.cors.methods=GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
```

My frontend runs on `localhost:3000` and backend on `localhost:8080`.

Frontend is in React, and i'm using `axios` to make the call like this:

```
      .post<ManagerView>(`/manager`, managerToManagerView(data.manager), {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${data.accessToken}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })

...

      .delete<boolean>(`/manager/${userId}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${data.accessToken}`,
        },
      })
```

### The Error

In Firefox, I get the following error when i make a Delete request.

```
XHR OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/rest/manager/auth0|63de17288141500bc6ac65e0
CORS Missing Allow Origin

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/rest/manager/auth0|63de17288141500bc6ac65e0. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 400.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/rest/manager/auth0|63de17288141500bc6ac65e0. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

Here's a screenshot from the Browser's devtools:

[image]

As you can see, just before the `DELETE` request, there is a `POST`  request and the preflight for that is successful.

This is the details of the preflight which fails (the one before `DELETE`):
[image: failing cors request on firefox]

Also for comparison, here is the preflight request which doesn't fail (The one before `POST`)
[image: non-failing cors request on firefox]

- This error only happens on `DELETE` or `PUT`. Other methods (`POST` and `GET`) are working fine.
- This error only happens on Firefox, not on Chrome or Edge
- Another interesting detail might be that on Chrome it doesn't work if I don't supply the `Authorization` header

I have tried various CORS settings for Quarkus however nothing works.

Comment: Try adding `quarkus.http.cors.headers=Authorization,Content-Type`.

Comment: @jub0bs Does not work. I have also tried: `quarkus.http.cors.headers=accept,origin,authorization,content-type,x-requested-with` but still not working.

Comment: Ok, please take a screenshot of the problematic preflight request (incl. headers) in your browser's Network tab and add it to your question.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of both the failing and non-failing request. Comparing the two, they both look almost identical except for the fact that the failing one doesn't get any headers back.